# Retrieve IMAP email based on date AND time?

Tags: date, time, imap

I'm trying to retrieve email using IMAP that's less than a certain number of hours old.  I've looked over the specifications, and there is a SINCE method that accepts an RFC date.  However, it ignores the time and timezone.  Is there another method I can use to retrieve email based on date as well as time?  Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[RFC 5032](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5032) documents the WITHIN extension which introduces the search keyword `YOUNGER`, which is what you're looking for.

For example, to search for all emails less than 2 hours old:

```
a SEARCH YOUNGER 7200
```